# Problems with Git Push

Tags: git, gitlab, push, pull

The git push command has been causing me some major frustration. Here is a quick description of my situation:

On the GitLab website, I can create a file and then successfully sync that file to my computer using "git pull origin master".

However, if I try to make any changes via the command prompt (say, using "touch foo" followed by "git add foo") and then try to send those changes to GitLab using "git push origin master", I receive a message saying "Everything up-to-date"; however, no changes are reflected on the gitlab website.

Any ideas for troubleshooting?

Comment: touching won't do anything, what else have you tried?

Comment: Sorry; I am new to GitLab! Let me try to explain this in a different way:
I am only using "touch" to create a file so that I can then commit the change and then push that same file to GitLab using "git push origin master." This is the command that is not working.

Comment: Separate git and gitlab. They are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `git commit` step. You did `git add` staging the `foo` file and followed it with `git push` which correctly says that there is no new commits to push.

What you want to do is:

```
$ touch foo
$ git add foo
$ git commit -m "Adding foo"
$ git push origin master
```

Comment: Ha! I feel so foolish! This solved my problem - thank you so much for replying. :)